# spacesuit airconditioning

Tags: spacesuits

I read that during the EVA, the astronauts body temp. was maintained by the PLSS, by rejecting the body heat, using porous plate sublimator. In this porus plate, water was made to evaporate into space vacuum. Thus we were constantly wasting some amount of water. This would also have been a limiting factor on the duration of EVA (other than Oxygen stock etc.)

Am I correct, or is there any other method of temp. control?

Comment: You are correct and this question is a duplicate. (Searches....)

Comment: @OrganicMarble the suit-cooling question I know about are [How have space suits dissipated the heat removed from astronauts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15191/12102) and [Will suits worn on Mars lose kilograms of “expendable water” each time they are used?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16901/12102) but there may be more.

Comment: It was the former I was thinking about, thanks! I was on my primitive device but just switched so I could answer a question.

Comment: There are other limiting factors for the duration of the EVA, electric energy to operate the suit, scrubber to remove the exhaled carbon dioxide and the condition of the astronaut itself.

Comment: There is another method of removing heat energy, a heat pump as used for aircondition. But a heat pump with radiators would be too heavy and bulky and would need too much electrical energy for a PLSS. Reliability of such a complex system would be too low. Of course EVA time will be limited by battery capacity.