# Do any spacesuit designs (including prototypes, conceptual, etc) use radiators rather than open-loop cooling?

Tags: spacesuits, eva

Answers to: [How have space suits dissipated the heat removed from astronauts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15191/how-have-space-suits-dissipated-the-heat-removed-from-astronauts) explain how USA suits currently use open-loop cooling.

Typically, space suits must dissipate several hundred watts of heat from the body of an EVAing astronaut.

The Apollo and Shuttle/ISS EVA suits used open-loop cooling by the sublimation of water into (near) vacuum, which introduced an additional consumable and is unworkable in an atmosphere.

Have any spacesuits been designed that use radiators (and presumably heat pumps) to dissipate heat? My calculations suggest that with a radiator temperature of ~ 500 K (227 deg C) you can get around 3.5 kW per square meter, which seems manageable.

Comment: But how do you get the radiator up to such drastic temperatures?  You need some sort of heat pump/heat exchanger.

Comment: [but](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(thermodynamics)) so maybe  600 K?

Comment: I could have sworn this was asked already.

Comment: @DrSheldon that is the question linked in the first sentence of this question, which went on to explain why this question is different even before the edit just now. I think this is a reckless close vote because this question "Have any spacesuits **been designed** that use radiators" *is not answered there*, where answers are only about suits that *have been used* historically. This is a forward-thinking question about suits that don't require expendable water.

Comment: @DrSheldon Answers to [Will suits worn on Mars lose kilograms of “expendable water” each time they are used?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16901/12102) do not describe any *designs* either, so this is not a duplicate of that either. Could you please consider removing your vote to close and allow users the ability to post new answers here?

Comment: As far as "design", there are plenty of "design"s. Just Google "spacesuit radiator" and click on any of the first 200 or so links. Did you mean "have been used before"? (In which case the answer is probably no. According to [this report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20000081742.pdf), NASA suits can radiate 2800 BTU/hr (820.6 W); a 37°C panel would need almost 2 square meters of space. This just isn't available on a spacesuit, so you need either a heat pump or open-cycle. You choose by picking the one that's passively safe—and now you see why one hasn't flown . . .)

Comment: It's worth noting that a potential out-of-the-box answer would be the Gemini spacesuits—which were reported to have radiators, but on the capsule instead, the suit and capsule tied by umbilical. Unfortunately for that narrative, the dependence of the Gemini spacesuits on the capsule for thermal regulation [was](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19680016105.pdf) in source water to expend.

Comment: @imallett Are porous plate sublimators really passively safe?

Comment: I mean, I can imagine problems existing, but it's kindof literally just a block of ice. To me, this seems simpler and less failure-prone than a heat pump—even a simple, miniaturized one. To be clear, I don't think such a solution is impossible (and it may even be a good idea given the value of volatiles at our current level of space development), but I think this is the reason why we have not seen it so far.

Comment: Some of the new lunar suit designs use a membrane evaporator, so still open loop.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwUvh9sluOA

Answer (score 5):

During the service module spacewalk during Apollo 15-17, all three astronauts' spacesuits were connected by umbilicals to the command module.  This included the closed-loop cooling water circuit, which dissipated heat using radiators on the service module.

(Technically answers the question, but perhaps not in the spirit of the question.)

Comment: Technically correct is the best kind of correct.