# What spacesuits did the Apollo astronauts wear on Earth in their training for the Moon?

Tags: apollo-program, spacesuits, lunar-landing

Even on the Moon the Apollo spacesuits were so heavy and bulky that the Apollo astronauts couldn't move quite well in them, except in the Apollo 15-17 missions where they were improved. However on Earth where they weigh about 6 times more I wonder how they could use them for training? I think I've read somewhere that they didn't use them at all on Earth. But what suits did they use as alternatives then?

Comment: My answer [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37292/26446) answers this question, even though that question is about spacesuit cooling during training.

Comment: @DrSheldon Thank you. Your answer is very good too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Smithsonian museum](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/pressure-suit-apollo-a7-l-shepard-training/nasm_A19750836000) web page.

> This spacesuit was worn by astronaut Alan Shepard, and was used for
>   training purposes prior to the Apollo 14 mission in January/February
>   1971.
>
> Training suits were identical to those worn during flight, and were
>   designed to familiarize the astronaut to the weight and "feel" of the
>   suits to be used during the mission. As with the flight suits,
>   training suits could be pressurized and worn with relative comfort for
>   up to 115 hours in conjunction with the liquid cooling garment.

"*... that they didn't use them at all on Earth.*" **That is wrong!**

[image]

See also this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35649/did-apollo-11-astronauts-rehearse-their-photoshoots-on-earth/35650#35650) with many links to more training photos of astronauts wearing space suits on Earth. Another [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37282/how-were-apollo-spacesuits-cooled-during-simulations-rehearsals-on-earth?rq=1) about cooling the suits during simulations on Earth.

But they used simulated backpacks for training too:

[image]

Image from the book [Science Training History of the Apollo Astronauts](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/strategies/Phinney_NASA-SP-2015-626.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! My quote you're mentioning is not wrong because I referred to the suits they wore on the Moon. They are not identical to the ones on Earth as you say. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question at all.

Comment: @user30007 Please read the quote from the Smithsonian carefully. I did not say "They are not identical to the ones on Earth". Only the backpacks were modified for training but not the suits.

Comment: That is what I mean, they were redesigned despite being technically the same ones.